# Silverlight object restart when making the container div hidden then visible

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

So I have this aspx page with tabs and in one tab I have a silverlight object with 2 grids in it.

The tabs are basically clickable divs that show or hide the correspondent page div.

So when I modify something in the silverlight grids, change tab and then come back to the tab with the silverlight grids, the silverlight app is restarted ? But if I do not touch the silverlight part, the app doesn't restart?

Why? There is no postback done that would restart the silverlight app.?

The silverlight object is simply hidden when another tab is selected ?  Why is it restarting?

Thanks,

Gab

Comment: Did you solve this problem?